# Is it possible to create objects that are named after the values in a list?

Tags: python, arrays, string, csv

I have a list of file names, A1 & A2.

The load method creates a temporary list of the data held on the csv file.

Is it possible to create an instance of a class based off of the string (file name) passed?

```
patients_list = ["A1", "A2"]

def load_patient(patients_list):

    patient_data = []

    for i in range(len(patients_list)):
        with open(patients_list[i]+".csv", "rt") as patient_file:        
            patient_file_reader = csv.reader(patient_file, delimiter=',')
            for row in patient_file_reader:
                patient_data.append(row)           

            patients_list[i] = patientClass(patient_data)  #can the string value be converted to an obj?
```

My goal is to have two objects named A1 and A2 (each containing the csv data).

Is this possible? I have searched the internet for a solution but have come up short.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible by some hacks like adding entries into `globals()`, and no you do not want that.

The fact is that you could not even propose a possible syntax, because nothing is easy on that way. The common and robust way to name dynamic objects is to use a dictionary:

```
patient_obj = {}
...
for i in range(...):
    ...
    patient_obj[patient_list[i]] = patientClass(patient_data)
```

Comment: Thank you. So in the case of your solution, how would I call a particular object from the dictionary? patient_obj[1].get_something?

Comment: It is a plain dictionnary, so you just use it: `patient_obj['A1']`, or `patient_obj[name]` where name is an element from `patient_list`.